# How to get the log results for last 1hr through the logging query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

Is there a way to get log results for **last 1hr**,2hr ..etc using the **logging query** itself? without using the Time Range selector in the GUI.

Comment: For now, no, you can't. But it will change in 2022 if you sink your logs in a custom logging bucket.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for your response, already we have our logs in the logging bucket only, when can we really expect this time range filter in the logging query?is this thing is in development?

Comment: I haven't that information. The feature is currently in private preview. You can expect it in Q1 or Q2 I guess.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The filter can refer to the log entry timestamp field, for example

```
timestamp >= "2022-01-20T00:00:00Z"
```

but there's no way to refer to a relative time.

There is at least one example on https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library-preview#gae-filters

Answer (score 0):

If you alter the URL of a Logs Explorer page by removing the fields which define the time range, this new URL will always open a page that defaults to "now" and shows the most recent log entries.